# Do we have a unit to count one particular type of animal?

Tags: word-request

We have a lot of words to count human beings, for example, individuals, men, women, people, teachers. But when it comes to animals, it seems to me that we can only use the common noun referring to that kind of animal to count it. For example, if I want to count elephants, I'll have to say, "1000 elephants, 1001 elephants,..."

It's different from my language, in which we have a unit to count animals in general, just like we have "people", "individuals", e.t.c to count human beings.

**So, are there such words in English?**

Comment: We can say *The circus has a **six-elephant** rail-car which it uses to transport these large animals by train.*  And English does have different words for *groups* of animals, although it refers to the group as group, not as a count. https://arapahoelibraries.org/blogs/post/names-for-groups-of-animals/

Comment: It might help if you explain why you need such a word or how it would be used in a way that you can't use "elephants". And maybe provide sentences you want to use it in. If you want something slightly shorter than "elephant", you can say "I saw 100 of them" with anything, for instance.

Comment: _Men, women, teachers_ are not 'words for counting', but words for particular genders or occupations.

Comment: Units in English are not grammatically tied to the number, they are simply nouns used to describe what you are numbering. Any applicable noun can be used with a number to say what it is that you are counting. Thus, you could describe the same group as 100 elephants, 100 animals, 100 large animals, 100 female animals, etc.

Comment: Note that "individual" is not a word that inherently refers to a human. Especially in scientific writing, it's not uncommon to use "individual" to refer to an animal, as in "most of the rats took five minutes or more to make it through the maze, but four individuals managed to get through much faster"--here, it's clear that "four individuals" refers to four of the rats involved in the experiment.

Comment: **Teacher** is a word for a specialized role of a human being; there are words for specialized roles of animals, such as **pet** or **mount**. For many animals there are words for male and female animals (for example, **buck** and **doe**) just as **man** and **woman** are words for male and female humans. Conversely, the words we use to "count" people are grammatically just like the ones we use to "count" animals. What is your language?

Comment: I notice that you have asked about 60 questions now,  but you have only accepted one answer.  Is that because the other 59 questions haven't been answered acceptably?  If one of the answers below solves your problem, consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses!

Comment: @JamesK Yes, I'll try to keep that function in mind. I speak Vietnamese, for your question. We're close to China, so I guess that's why we all have a word to count animals.

Comment: @StuartF It's because sometimes the name of the animals are too long. Imagine writing an essay talking about the number of frill-necked lizards and having to repeat that again and again. Moreover, using a counter doesn't sound repetitive to me, but repeating the names of the animals, especially when they are long, gives me that impression.

Comment: By the way, sometimes I feel like clicking "accept" an answer will end the discussion, while I still want to hear others' opinions because native speakers disagree with each other pretty frequently.

Comment: Re frill necked lizards.  I've edited my answer to address that point.  It doesn't lead to repetition in English

Comment: When your language has a unit to count animals in general, what language is that and what unit, please?

Men or women are specific to humans but what's wrong with males or females? What's wrong with leaders or followers and yes, in many cases teachers and learners?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

English doesn't have "counters".  There are a number of specialized units, like "grams" or "seconds", but the words that you mention "men", "individuals", "teachers" and so on, are just nouns and not used particularly for counting.  This contrasts with, for example Japanese in which numerals are normally combined with a counting word.

So in English one says "five people", "five men", "five teachers" or "five elephants".  English does not consider "people", "men" or "elephants" to be  counting words, just common nouns.

This doesn't lead to repetition, since you don't normally need to repeat the full noun.  If you are talking about (for example) "Frill necked lizards", you would use a pronoun, or just the number "five", For example "A-- Did you see any frill-necked lizards today? B-- Yes, I saw five. (B) Does not need to say "Five frill-necked lizards" or even "five lizards".  In the same way if you ask "--How many people were at the party? -- "About twenty".  You don't need to say "twenty individuals".

Comment: In Japanese you would say "5-nin of people, 5-nin of men, 5-nin of teachers and 5-dou of elephants, where "nin" and "dou" are essentially untranslatable words used for counting humans and *large* animals. And one of the challenges of learning Japanese is learning which counter is used with which noun.  But it does offer opportunities for word play, such as the father telling the bus driver that he needed tickets for 3-hiki of children, where "hiki" is the counter for small animals.  But counters are as alien to English as grammatical number is to Japanese.

Comment: In Chinese it is the same way - and knowing that Japan imported the Chinese system of writing, along with several other features, one might suspect the use of 'measure words' came along with the characters.

Comment: Yes, it is an example of an East Asian Sprachbund.  Common features in several unrelated languages.

Comment: @JamesK My favorite thing about -tou vs -hiki for big and small animals is that rabbits aren't 3-tou or 3-hiki; they're 3-wa, meaning they're birds.

Comment: That's like the capybara is classed as a "fish", so it can be eaten on Friday and during Lent by Catholics in South America.

Comment: @JamesK that is awesome! Is there a source?

Comment: "monks declared the beaver a fish-like aquatic animal and voilà, it was a permitted delicacy on the easter menu" - https://www.imupro.at/blog/allgemein/als-biber-fische-wurden/

Comment: What about when you have to talk about the number of the lizards, for example, in structures like "the number of ..." and "... population"? You have to include the name then. But if you only write "the number of lizards" or "lizard population", it might be misleading.

Comment: I can't imagine any real example in which that would be a problem.  "The number of lizards has decreased on the island, with their population dropping to about 500 last year."

Answer (score 12):

We sometimes use "head" in that way, but normally only for domestic animals kept in herds especially cattle: "thirty head of cattle".

Other than that, there are no such words. We just say "three cats" or "twelve giraffes".

Comment: And in case it's not clear: it can be acceptable to have no word after the number at all. "How many elephants are there?" "There are ten."

Comment: Yes, "head" was the only example I could think of as a singular counting word; though we do also have some counting words that imply more than one per unit (two braces of pheasants, six dozen eggs, four yoke of oxen, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

None of the words you are using in your "human" examples are used to *count* human beings; they are used to *describe* human beings.
They are just common names, and you would use one or another depending on what *kind* of human you are referring to, not on *how many* humans there are.

With that in mind, there are certain animal species for which you could use different names just like with the humans in your example:

- Genderless group

  - 1000 people
  - 1000 cattle
  - 1000 dogs
  - 1000 chicken
- Male

  - 1000 men
  - 1000 bulls
  - 1000 dogs (maybe [alphas](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alpha), [studs](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stud))
  - 1000 [roosters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rooster)
- Female

  - 1000 women
  - 1000 cows
  - 1000 [bitches](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bitch)
  - 1000 [hens](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hen)
- Young

  - 1000 children
  - 1000 [calves](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calf)
  - 1000 [puppies](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puppy)
  - 1000 [chicks](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chick)
- Work

  - 1000 teachers
  - 1000 [oxen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ox)
  - 1000 [hounds](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hound)
  - 1000 [cocks](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cock) (as in cockfighting)

Same goes for horses (mares, stallions, foals...) and most other domestic animals.

It's just that most of us know *a lot* more specific names for different kinds of humans than for different kinds of animals. You can check online sources like [this one](https://livestockconservancy.org/resources/animal-terms/) to learn more animal terms.

In any case, the words you mentioned are not "counters" and there's no such thing as different types of numbers for different types of animals.

Comment: the uk term for roosters is cockerels, or just cocks (just for interest)

Answer (score -1):

When we say "people" or "individuals", it's normally clear that you're speaking about human beings and not about animals.

Terms like "animals" or "creatures" are probably the most obvious equivalent to "people". But these terms could include animals of all kinds, not just one kind that you mean to count.

Terms like "life forms" or "lives" are sometimes used to refer to humans *and* animals collectively, but again, there would be no way of knowing that you only meant certain kinds of animals and not others.

The only way I can see to refer to a particular animal without using the name of that animal is to use a 'family' name. For example, you can refer to horses as "equines", although that could also include other animals such as donkeys. Likewise, "canines" for dogs, "bovines" for cows.

Comment: In my experience, "individuals" is used for animals as well as humans; e.g. "The format for listing is as follows: species name followed by number of individuals" https://www.audubon.org/news/the-all-time-highest-counts-individual-species-united-states-cbcs-1-120

Comment: @coneslayer the link you gave uses individual as an *adjective* before the word 'species' in the headline. That isn't the same as using it as a noun for a human. I accept that, later on in the article it uses it as a noun, but it is highly unusual. Individuality is not something ascribed to wild animals. I feel that they had to use that word after talking about counts of *species*. I also acknowledge that owned animals and household pets are often anthropomorphised and may be called 'individuals' to reflect their personality. But these are exceptions and I don't think it answers this question.

Comment: I don't know why you brought up the headline of the article, I didn't say anything about that. I quoted the sentence I was referring to.

I disagree that it's "highly unusual" to refer to animals as individuals, in contexts where that's something useful to do.

"A total of 776 samples from 586 individuals were included in this study." https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-024-55847-3

"...the practice promotes genetic mixing between individuals from outside the islands with those originating from the islands." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peregrine_falcon

etc.